# how to get the particular index(n th position) element from a list of json values in postgres sql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

this my json object that already stored in my postgres 11 database

> [{"user_id": 0, "user_name": "", "user_role": "", "start_timestamp":
> "2020-09-08 04:01:31.636848", "end_timestamp": "2020-09-08
> 04:01:31.636848", "hold_timestamp_list": [], "handover_link": "",
> "curr_state": "To be Alloted", "is_complete": 1, "is_onhold": 0},
> {"user_id": 910, "user_name": "INM", "user_role": "",
> "start_timestamp": "2020-09-09 05:11:06.476766", "end_timestamp": "",
> "hold_timestamp_list": [{"s": "2020-09-09 05:11:07.359749", "e": ""}],
> "handover_link": "", "curr_state": "Authoring", "is_complete": 0,
> "is_onhold": 1}]

how can i get the **user_name** from last index (i.e :  index 2 ,value =

> {"user_id": 910, "user_name": "INM", "user_role": "",
> "start_timestamp": "2020-09-09 05:11:06.476766", "end_timestamp": "",
> "hold_timestamp_list": [{"s": "2020-09-09 05:11:07.359749", "e": ""}],
> "handover_link": "", "curr_state": "Authoring", "is_complete": 0,
> "is_onhold": 1}

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative index to get the last element of the json array, like so:

```
mycol -> -1
```

If you want the corresponding user name:

```
mycol -> -1 ->> 'user_id'
```

Or maybe you want an integer result:

```
(mycol -> -1 ->> 'user_id')::int
```